# Changing the interception angle in autopilot for OBS or VOR in the G1000 from 30 to something more aggressive

Tags: autopilot, g1000

I am flying the G1000 and have noticed that if I program in an OBS TO or a VOR TO (this might apply to FROM as well), the angle at which I fly relative to my programmed in bearing is 30 degrees.

For example, if I am flying 180 and want to fly to an airport nearby with an OBS setting of 250 and put this in and turn on NAV, the plane will turn to 220, which indeed will intercept 250 at some point. But if I am not far from the airport I am wanting to approach at 250, this interception will get me too close to the airport, by the time I reach 250. So I would like a more aggressive interception angle than 30... maybe 90? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual does not state any way to do that. You can adjust the vertical navigation flight path angle, but not the horizontal intercept angle. You'll have to fly that yourself. In addition, in this case you should be telling the G1000 where you want it to go, rather than which heading to go. If you just tell it the heading it will never figure out what it has to do to get you to that nearby airport, so in this case it is working as advertised.

Comment: Ok. I have scoured the online documentation and asked my instructor this and concur I don't have a clear answer to this either. 

By "adjust the vertical navigation flight path angle", are you referring to the fact this gets indirectly set by my setting the VSI or IAS I want to fly to reach a new altitude?

I don't quite follow what you mean by telling the G1000 where I want to go rather than heading. I thought the OBS does exactly the former, where I have a waypoint and I am saying "Approach this point on this radial". Problem here being I reach it when I am upon it.

Comment: Search the docs for flight path. It will tell you. OBS just tells the G1000 in which direction you want the aircraft to go, not to what waypoint. I would strongly suggest you at least take one of the many online courses for the G1000.

Comment: Actually I did take a flight in the sim with an instructor. We did not spend a lot of time on the OBS. Perhaps I misunderstood it. So the point of it is not to actually reach that waypoint but rather use that waypoint almost like it is a VOR station and choose the radial along which to fly, which comes down then to a direction dictated by the TO radial coming out of that waypoint?